# How can I trace why a variable is not populated at init time in Kivy GUI?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

How is it possible that the Kivy GUI app is not load the whole code at the time of initialization?

Is it possible that when we called some function so the execution of the code which is inside that function starts at runtime.

The code is:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.selectioncontrol import MDCheckbox
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivymd.uix.fitimage import FitImage
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import RoundedRectangularElevationBehavior
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
class my_mdcard(MDCard,RoundedRectangularElevationBehavior):
    pass

class Item_Menu(Screen,MDBoxLayout):
    list_of_information={"checkbox":[],"labels":[],"quantity":[]}
    selected_items= {"checkbox": [], "labels": [], "quantity": []}
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Item_Menu,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint=(1,0.9)
        self.pos_hint={"top":1}
        self.orientation="vertical"
        scrollbarwin=ScrollView()
        content_box=BoxLayout(orientation='vertical',padding=dp(8),spacing=dp(8),size_hint=(1,None))
        content_box.bind(minimum_height=content_box.setter('height'))
        for i in range(0,50):
            Template_card= my_mdcard(
                size_hint_y=None,
                size_hint_x=.960,
                height = dp(100),
                padding = dp(4),
                pos_hint={'center_y': .5, 'center_x': .490},
                radius = [20,],
                elevation = 4,

            )
            checkbox=MDCheckbox(
                size_hint=(None, None),
                size= (dp(48),dp(48)),
                pos_hint={'center_y': .5}
            )
            checkbox.bind(active=lambda instance,value:self.Selected_checkbox(instance,value))
            self.list_of_information["checkbox"].append(checkbox)
            image_box=MDBoxLayout(adaptive_size=True)
            image=FitImage(
                source="D:/Study/Python/Kivy/images/2.jpg",
                size_hint= (None, None),
                height=dp(80),
                width=dp(130),
                radius=[12,],
                pos_hint={'center_y':0.5}

            )
            image_box.add_widget(image)
            text_box=MDBoxLayout(orientation="vertical",adaptive_height=True,pos_hint={'center_y':0.5},padding=[12,0,0,0])
            item_name=MDLabel(text=f"item{i+1}",font_style="H5",size_hint=(1,None),bold=True,theme_text_color="Primary")
            item_name.bind(texture_size=item_name.setter('size'))
            self.list_of_information["labels"].append(item_name)
            price=MDLabel(text=u"Price: \u20B910/per",font_style="Subtitle1",size_hint=(1,None),bold=True,theme_text_color="Hint")
            price.bind(texture_size=price.setter('size'))
            quantitybox=MDBoxLayout(orientation='vertical',adaptive_height=True,size_hint_x=0.2,pos_hint = {'center_y': .5,'center_x':0.5})
            quantityfield=MDTextField(
                hint_text= "Quantity",
                mode= "rectangle",
                size_hint=(None,None),
                width=dp(80),
                height= dp(40),
                padding=[0,0,15,0]
            )
            self.list_of_information["quantity"].append(quantityfield)
            quantitybox.add_widget(quantityfield)
            Template_card.add_widget(checkbox)
            Template_card.add_widget(image_box)
            Template_card.add_widget(text_box)
            text_box.add_widget(item_name)
            text_box.add_widget(price)
            Template_card.add_widget(quantitybox)
            content_box.add_widget(Template_card)
        scrollbarwin.add_widget(content_box)
        buttonbox=MDBoxLayout(orientation="vertical",pos_hint={"top":0.1},adaptive_height=True)
        button=MDRaisedButton(text="Selected!!!",size_hint=(1,0.2))
        
        button.bind(on_release=lambda x:self.Change_window(x))
        buttonbox.add_widget(button)
        self.add_widget(scrollbarwin)
        self.add_widget(buttonbox)
    def Selected_checkbox(self,instance,value):
        for i in range(0,len(self.list_of_information["checkbox"])):
            if instance==self.list_of_information["checkbox"][i] and value== True:
                self.selected_items["labels"].append(self.list_of_information["labels"][i])
                self.selected_items["quantity"].append(self.list_of_information["quantity"][i])
            elif instance==self.list_of_information["checkbox"][i] and value== False :
                self.selected_items["labels"].remove(self.list_of_information["labels"][i])
                self.selected_items["quantity"].remove(self.list_of_information["quantity"][i])
    def Change_window(self,instance):
        MyApp.sm.current="Item Description"
class Description_item(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Description_item,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        print(Item_Menu.selected_items)
        wholeContentBoxContainer=MDBoxLayout(orientation="vertical")

        for item in range(0,len(Item_Menu.selected_items["labels"])):
                label=MDLabel(text=Item_Menu.selected_items["labels"][item].text)
                print(Item_Menu.selected_items["labels"][item].text)
                quantity=MDLabel(text=Item_Menu.selected_items["quantity"][item].text)
                wholeContentBoxContainer.add_widget(label)
                wholeContentBoxContainer.add_widget(quantity)
        self.add_widget(wholeContentBoxContainer)
class MyApp(MDApp):
    sm=ScreenManager()
    def build(self):
        self.sm.add_widget(Item_Menu(name="Item Menu"))
        self.sm.add_widget(Description_item(name="Item Description"))
        self.theme_cls.theme_style="Dark"
        return self.sm


MyApp().run()
```

When you  run this code so you will see that at the time of initialization of the app the `print function`  is getting print the the dictionary "selected_items" which I never want to be print it out  at the time of initialization of the code.

Here is a picture will help you to better understand:

[image: The arrow show the Dictionary which is print out at the time of initialization of the app]

Due to this reason I am unable to access the data of the dictionary "selected_items" in the class "Description_item" because it points to empty list which is the value of the dictionary keys.

So how I can access the data of the dictionary "selected_items"?

Comment: Please read [ask] and make sure you understand that this is *not a discussion forum*. We need a *clear, specific question* - it should start with a question word like "why" or "how", and end with a question mark (`?`). You should also almost certainly *show some actual code*.

Comment: Code that is within an `__init__()` method is run at initialization. If you don't want code to run at initialization, then you should not put it in an `__init__()` method.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I have implemented your solution which you explained to me but from this method it is not getting run at initialization as well as the whole kivy gui app is not working. it is not show anything to do in it. I just want that  when the class is called by performing any task by the user so then the class will get start its execution of code but it is not working as a desirable result. if you have any other solution for it by which this issue is also getting solved, so please suggest me!!! Thank You!!

Comment: I have replaced the title with a useful one. Please feel free to edit, but keep titles specific ("please help me" is not thought to be a question here).